# subprocess checkoutput error

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to check the usage of check_output using he below script and running into compilation error,where am I going wrong?

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output

#result = subprocess.check_output(['your_program.exe', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
SCRIPT_ROOT=subprocess.check_output(["pwd","shell=True"])
print SCRIPT_ROOT

def main ():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from subprocess import check_output
ImportError: cannot import name check_output
```

Comment: This is an unrelated side note, but: Did you add the `from subprocess import check_output` just to try to debug this problem? If not, you don't want to do that when you're already `import`ing the whole module, and then explicitly using it qualified (as `subprocess.check_output`) in your code. (Also, it's a bit odd to have the `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom and also have module-level procedural code. If the code doesn't have to be `import`able, don't bother with the `__main__` stuff. If it does, don't put module-level code that shouldn't run on `import`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`check_output` has been introduced in Python 2.7. If you're using an earlier version of python, it's just not there.

Alternative is to use `Popen`.

```
output = subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Proof of this can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.7.html).

> New function: the subprocess module’s check_output() runs a command
>   with a specified set of arguments and returns the command’s output as
>   a string when the command runs without error, or raises a
>   CalledProcessError exception otherwise.

Demo of the substitute.

```
import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen(['pwd'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = cmd.communicate()[0]
print cmd.returncode
print output
```

Output

```
> python p.py
/Users/vlazarenko/tests
```

The only real difference is that `Popen` won't throw an exception when command returns a non-zero code.

Comment: I am having check_call working on the same linux machine using 2.6.5,are you saying check_output is added later after check_call?

Comment: But your code doesn't actually check the output—it never even _gets_ the output. So it's not really a direct substitute.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't get the output?

Comment: @favoretti: Sorry, I mean the return code—the way you tell whether or not "the command runs without error". That's the whole point of `check_call` and `check_output`, and you're not doing it.

Comment: Rewrote the example so that you can pull out return code, you'll need to check it yourself though :) I suppose an `if` is trivial enough.

Comment: Does `communicate` guarantee that `returncode` is available when it finishes? The docstring clearly says it will "Wait for process to terminate", but is that the same as "call `wait()` or equivalent", or is there anything else that guarantees it? Because I notice that `check_output` does `process.poll()` rather than `process.returncode`, and there must be some reason for that…

Comment: The reason for that is that `communicate()` sets `returncode` indirectly, rather than directly and it will not be set until process will be terminated. So basically it _will_ fail in some edge cases.

Comment: @abarnert: either `.returncode` is guaranteed to be set after `.communicate()` returns and it is a documentation bug if it is not mentioned or it is a bug in `check_output()` because it treats `.poll() is None` as success. At least current `.communicate()` implementation calls `.wait()` therefore `.returncode` is set in it i.e., the documentation might need to be updated to reflect that if "Wait for process to terminate" is not explicit enough.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: You're missing the point that `returncode` may not be available until you (directly or indirectly) call `poll` or `wait`, because calling `poll` or `wait` is what sets it (at least on POSIX), not the process exiting. So, `check_output` not caring if `poll() is None` is not at all the same thing as never calling `poll()`. And if I understand favoretti correctly, this actually _does_ happen with code that naively uses `communicate`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: And really, this is more of an argument for using the `subprocess32` module than for copy-pasting the 2.7 code. If the functionality isn't properly documented, but is relied on by internal code, it's conceivable that this internal code that does the right thing in 2.7 doesn't do the right thing in 2.6 (or does on Windows but not POSIX, or does on all CPython platforms but not Jython, or…). In practice, I and hundreds of others have been doing this since 2.7 came out, but that doesn't mean we _should_ have been…

Comment: @abarnert: you might have missed: "`.communicate()` calls `.wait()` *therefore `.returncode` is set in it*". It strongly implies that I am aware that `.wait()` sets `.returncode`. To rephrase my previous comment, given: 1. `check_output()` uses `if .poll():` instead of `if .poll() != 0:` 2. `check_` must raise exception if `.returncode != 0` Follows: `.returncode == 0` if `check_` returns **=>** `.poll()` can't return `None` **=>** `.returncode` is set before `.communicate()` returns and "the documentation might need to be update to reflect that" or "it is a bug (1) in `check_output()`" QED

Comment: @abarnert: I support your second comment if `subprocess32` delivers on its promises (less old 2.x bugs, rare new 3.x bugs) and 3rd party modules are an option in a project.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yes, but you're talking about the CPython 2.7 Windows and Unix implementations, right? It _could_ be a documentation bug, and therefore still something you can rely on, but it could also be implementation-specific that you can't rely on (unless you only care about, e.g., CPython 2.6), and there's no way to know that a priori.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `check_output` in 2.6. But if you look at the [2.7 source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py), it's trivial.

In fact, a common way to deal with this is:

```
import subprocess
try:
    check_output = subprocess.check_output
except AttributeError:
    def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
        # lines 537-545 copied and pasted from 2.7 source
```

This does of course require that your code be PSFL-compatible (which it almost certainly is, but if it matters, I wouldn't take legal advice from a random guy on SO).

Another option is to use [`subprocess32`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/subprocess32/3.2.3), a backport of the 3.2.3 `subprocess` module to Python 2.4+, which gives you not only the new 2.7 features and fixes, but a bunch of newer ones. (Personally, whenever I'm writing 2/3 code, I end up writing `with subprocess.Popen…` and have to either change it to `with contextlib.closing(subprocess.Popen…` or `with subprocess32.Popen`…)

Comment: Heh, even without going to that source at first I reinvented almost the same wheel in my answer, although the question author keeps saying my solution is not a replacement ;)

Comment: @favoretti: Yeah, but I wouldn't reinvent the wheel unless I needed to. It's too easy to forget edge cases, or write code that works on your Mac dev box but not on linux even though they're both POSIX, or… So, unless I'm at a company with paranoid lawyers, I'd rather copy-paste—or, maybe even better, `pip install subprocess32`.

Comment: I tested on both MacOS and Linux ;) Even on 2.5 python :) But sure, better well stolen than poorly invented.

Comment: @favoretti: I actually had a real-life app that worked 100% on OS X, FreeBSD, and linux 2.2-2.4, but failed very, very rarely on linux 2.6+, all because of a bad assumption about effectively the same thing `Popen.wait()` does. Maybe a case of once bitten, 65535 times shy…

Comment: @abamert: By all means, don't get me wrong, I'm not arguing your point in any way to the contrary - I concur :) Although our dude already asked another question abusing the code I suggested without even upvoting :(

Comment: @favoretti: be nice. OP doesn't have enough rep to upvote and there is a time limit before an answer can be accepted so OP might not know that it can be done (SO interface is complicated, put yourself in new user shoes)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I am nice, I'm trying to talk him through in his next question :) I'm just ranting, sorry :)